# detecting changes to my program's focus

Tags: android

When other programs are open in Android, how do I know when my program loses focus or gains focus?

I've seen the [View `onFocusChanged` event](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFocusChanged%28boolean,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29), but I think that's unrelated (when i use a view changer).

How can this be done?

Comment: Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Activity`, you can override the life cycle methods. Specifically, onCreate, onStart, onResume, onPause, onStop and onDestroy. The most useful ones are:

- `onCreate`: great for one time initialization.
- `onResume`: refresh your data because your app is about to take foreground again.
- `onPause`: save your data and stop anything that doesn't need to be running while your app doesn't have the foreground.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle for a complete overview of these methods and your activities life cycle.